# PK Violation after transactional replication

Tags: sql-server-2008, replication

I have an application set up with transactional replication being pushed to a standby machine that will be used for emergency failovers. The replication appears to be working, any inserts made to Server 1 will automatically appear at Server 2.

However, I can't quite get the failover working. In the scenario that Server 1 becomes unavailable (which is the only scenario where Server 2 will ever be used, so the replication is one-way), the idea is that work should continue at Server 2, and that the transition should be somewhat seamless since all data has already been replicated.

But when moving to Server 2, after making sure that all updates on Server 1 have been transferred, I keep getting primary key violation exceptions, for some tables.

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_TableA'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.TableA'.

A simple query such as

```
INSERT INTO TableA (Field1, Field2, TableB_ID) VALUES ('a','b', 6)
```

will yield the above error. It seems that when I instruct the table to assign an identity of its own, by omitting it from the query (`TableA` has an `ID int identity(1,1)` field), SQL Server will auto-assign an ID that violates a PK constraint. Why would this be?

---

`TableA` has a trigger for `INSERT` and `DELETE` that does a simple denormalization job

```
UPDATE TableB
SET Count = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM TableA WHERE TableB.ID = TableA.TableB_ID)
WHERE ID IN(
    -- Fetch affected ID's from deleted or inserted rows
    SELECT DISTINCT TableB_ID FROM deleted
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT TableB_ID FROM inserted
)
```

This was accidentally not a part of the Server 2 database at the time of the replication, and I inserted it afterwards. Consistency in the `TableB.Count` field is not critical for the task at hand. The PK Violation occurred before the trigger existed in Server 2, as well as after creating it.

---

At both Publisher and Subscriber, the ID field that is yielding the violations has the following definition:

```
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL
```

I suppose the `NOT FOR REPLICATION` part is redundant on the Publisher, as no replication job will ever write to it, but I can't see that it should be the cause of the problem, either.

Comment: The `IDENT`s and `max(ID)`s are correct on both sides?  I mean a situation like [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlreplication/thread/f62d9ed9-13f9-4e44-b789-522624092df9)

Comment: @dezso: `max(ID)` on the problematic table yields the same ID for both databases, yes. What do you mean by `IDENT` here, and how can I verify it? For what it's worth: For tables where I *can* insert, I notice that the new records receive IDs from `1`, although the replicated IDs are much higher. As long as the database recognizes that the higher IDs are in use, and skips them once reached, that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Then possibly a `DBCC CHECKIDENT(TableA)` can solve your problem?  (By IDENT I was to mean the last inserted value in the identity column.)

Comment: @dezso: `CHECKIDENT` on the subscriber yields: `Checking identity information: current identity value '18', current column value '91987'.` What does it mean that current identity value is 18? Is that what it's going to try to insert next? There is already records 18, 19, 20 in the table, and 91987 is the highest ID in the table; that has been pushed from the publisher.

Comment: It means that the subscriber wanted to issue 19 as the next ID (tried 18 on the last insert).  [`DBCC CHECKIDENT(TableA)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx) has set the seed automatically.

Comment: @dezso: Well no wonder it doesn't work then, but why would that problem have appeared in the first place? (Mind you, subsequent `CHECKIDENT` calls yields 18 so it doesn't automatically update that to something that will work, but perhaps that's not how it's supposed to work). So, If I, after the failover, execute `DBCC CHECKIDENT(TableA, (SELECT MAX(ID)+1 FROM TableA))` I won't have this problem? If that's the case, I'll settle with that, but if you know a neater solution/way to avoid the problem in the first place, please share :)

Comment: I don't know why but it seems like it happens.  There are quite a few questions around regarding this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like that the identity column on the subscriber side is out of sync.  Run `DBCC CHECKIDENT(TableA, RESEED)` (or just `DBCC CHECKIDENT(TableA)`) and your problem will be gone.  You can check the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx) here.

Comment: For the record, `DBCC CHECKIDENT(TableA)` didn't do the trick, but `DBCC CHECKIDENT(TableA, RESEED)` did. I thought `RESEED` would be the default? Could this be related to my issue? Oh well, question resolved.

Comment: @DavidHedlund - it is interesting, the doc says the two being equivalent.

Comment: They are different. Without RESEED, it just tells you what the current seed is. With, it resets it to match actual data

Comment: @gbn - edited the answer, thanks for the input.  Is it possible that the linked doc page is wrong?

Comment: Actually, I could be wrong now. I thought the default was NORESEED which matches what I said. Never assume, check!!